# Who was Theophylact?

Tags: church-history, church-fathers

As mentioned in [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60391/what-are-the-historical-arguments-against-a-literal-interpretation-of-luke-2244), [this commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/luke/22.htm) mentions one "Theophylact" who was apparently a contemporary of Athanasius. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophylact) only provides a list of figures who lived well past Athanasius's time, and in my research, I've only found information about the people on that list. Here's the quote from that commentary:

> Some (for instance, Theophylact) understand this "as it were" to signify that the expression, "drops of blood," was simply parabolic; but it is far better to understand the words in their literal sense, as our Church does when it prays, "By thine agony and bloody sweat." Athanasius even goes so far as to pronounce a ban upon those who deny this sweat of blood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theophylact was an Eastern Orthodox archbishop of Ohrid.  He is considered a saint.  He lived from about 1055-1107.

He was involved in two of the causal primary disputes after the Great Schism of 1054 about the filioque and nature of bread Christ used at the Last Supper (either leavened-Greek or unleavened-Latin).

He absolutely refused to bend on the first issue, though acknowledging the Latins may have lacked clear specific language on the issue.  On the second issue, he acknowledged that Christ would have used unleavened bread, but that it was not a binding tradition.

He is well respected for his exegesis of books of the Bible.

[History of the Christian Church, Volume IV: Mediaeval Christianity. A.D. 590-1073](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/hcc4.i.xiv.vii.html)

[Ohrid (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohrid)

[Theophylact of Ohrid (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophylact_of_Ohrid)

[Chrysostom Press](http://www.chrysostompress.org/)